# 4mA-20mA loop behaviour when out of range

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, current-source

I have a temperature sensor that records temperatures from 10ºC to 30ºC, but in my project they only want temperatures to be read in the range of 15-25 with 4ma when 15 and 20ma when 25.My problem is what is supposed to be the behaviour of a 4-20 loop when the sensor records <15 and > 25.Should it freeze on the minimum and maximum value or should it take 0 as value?
thanks

Comment: That's a question you should be asking "them".

Comment: Most control systems that I work with can read 0mA to about 24mA. In 4-20mA mode, anything less than 4mA or greater than 20mA is called "out of range (OOR)", which can be expanded into "low-OOR" or "high-OOR". Ideally you wouldn't provide more than 20mA to most circuits because if it's poorly designed on the receiver side, you can blow out the ADC. I can do it safely with industrial systems because they are designed for it.

Comment: I developed a product with 4-20 mA outputs and my requirement was to limit the outputs at 10% beyond the 4-20 mA range.  I interpreted that as outputting a minimum of 3.6 mA and a maximum of 22 mA.  It might be a good idea to go beyond the 4-20 mA range so that whatever is reading the output can know that the value is out-of-range and react appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you will implement a receiver or the transmitter for the current loop. Suppose you will make a 4-20mA transmitter. Usually the 4-20mA loop would give you 4mA at minimum and 20mA at maximum. Those 4mA serves to for a wire break detection and/or to supply the transmitter from the loop.

However I have seen industrial transmitters that they also have control of over range- too low or too high, it means the signal goes little below 4mA and little higher than 20mA.

[image]

Now, this is Siemens PLC 4-20mA transmitter, don't look DAC values dec&hex those are specific to that PLC. It goes from 0mA to 22.81mA, If you intend to build a tranmitter that is powered from the loop, so called passive transmitter (2 wire connection), then you won't be able to output less than cca. 3.2mA - it depends on power consumption of your transmitter. If you intend to build a active transmitter (4 wire: 2 wire loop + 2 wire supply), then it's up to you to decide if you want to go down to 0mA output (wire break can't be detected) or to stop diving at certain low value output.

Comment: Thank you Marko. The voltage for my loop comes from a LP Filter from the PWM of the micro and the loop is just a current source op amp with a 5V Source connected to the collector of the BJT.So quite a simple setup for now.I can quickly put the PWM Duty_Cycle to 0 and set the current to 0 I was just trying to understand what the industry standard was since im a student.

Answer (score 0):

You can go slightly beyond the rated range and still assume the numbers are reasonable, which is more or less a standard from the analog world, but also hard transition to a presumed failure might be done these days.

Below about 3.6mA or about perhaps 22mA can be considered a sensor or loop failure. A *sensor* failure into a *working* loop-powered transmitter might not be able to reduce its current much below 3.6mA because some current is needed to internally to power the circuitry. On the other hand, if the wiring fails the current will drop to zero.

For example, a broken thermocouple would typically manifest itself at the transmitter output as >>20mA current, which would cause (through a controller) the heat to be turned off, which is usually (but certainly not always) the safer alternative to turning it on. The exact limiting depends on the design but I've seen >30mA from a commercial transmitter.

Interpreting (say) > 20mA as 500°C on a 0~500°C transmitter would not be a good approach, in my opinion. For example, if the controller setpoint is set to 500.1°C the heat might never turn off, even as the plant melts.